# Extract a specific part of the path of a file

Tags: bash, shell-script

Taking this path to a file: `words/05_díj/díj_pct.txt` how I can extract only this part? `05`

What I want is to use that part as a value for an external variable for the execution of an awk script.

Example:

```
for f in words/*/*_pct.txt
do
  #So, I want to extract "05" from $f

  #To use it here
awk -v var -f script.awk "$f" >> words/results.txt
done
```

Comment: Is there a specific pattern to the directory `05_dij`? Are you simply after the first two characters, or could that sometimes be (e.g.) `1234_xyz` and you need the `1234`?  Please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: The subdirectory name will always be `05_whatever 06_whatever 08_whatever` . Only two digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

```
for f in words/*/*_pct.txt; do
  n=${f#*/}   # Remove everything till the first slash
  n=${n%%_*}  # Remove everything from the first underscore to the end
  awk -v var="$n" -f script.awk "$f" >> words/results.txt
done
```

Note you need to quote `-v var="$n"`, and if `$n` contain escaped sequences, they will be expanded.

Comment: But I want the argument of the awk script remains the full path. What I need is to store "05" in a variable. I don't want to alter the value of $f

Comment: I'm Trying this, to try. `var="words/05_díj/díj_pct.txt"; n=${var#*/}; n=${var%%_*}; echo $n` and the result is `words/05` not only "05"

Comment: @Firefly: Sorry, it's `var="words/05_díj/díj_pct.txt"; n=${var#*/}; n=${n%%_*}; echo "$n"`